# Relation on Krylov Spaces

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

Let $ K_n = \operatorname{span}\{b,Ab,\ldots,A^{n-1}b\} $. Also, show that $AK_n \subset K_n$ and $K_n = K_{n+1} = \cdots$.

These spaces are odd to me. Any ideas how to prove this?

Comment: It seems to me you must have missed a hypothesis, possibly that $n$ is the dimension of the space or the rank of $A$ or something like that. $\qquad$